# OpenUrl() property not working in Titanium 3.1.3

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have used Ti.Platform.openUrl() property to open a website link inside my Android App. But this "openUrl()" property works fine in Titanium 3.0.2 or lower versions. It's not working in Titanium 3.1.3 version. Could anyone suggest me a solution to this problem or an alternate method.

My code looks like below;

```
button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
Ti.Platform.openURL("https://www.google.co.in/");
});
```

Comment: There seems to be a [ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-3319) for this kind of error, though it is unresolved. Updating to the latest Titanium SDK 3.2.0 GA might help...

Answer (score 0):

Its Ti.Platform not Ti.platform

Comment: sorry.I have tried with Ti.Platform only. corrected the spelling mistake.

Comment: ok so are you opening google site or just a give a example..
if you are opening some other url then you just need to encode that url using encodeURI.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Global-method-encodeURIComponent

Comment: It's just an example. i'm opening other URL's exactly in same way as i mentioned above.

Comment: @Mitul: The problem is i'm getting runtime error like "Uncaught Error:java Exception occured - Ti.Platform.openURL()". It was working fine in Titanium 3.0.2 version. This error comes only when i use Titanium 3.1.3 version. I doesn't think encoding URL will solve the problem because i have been using the unencoded "Google links" previously(in 3.0.2) which works fine..

Comment: @Mitul: I have tried with encode/decode URIcomponents, still not working.